# Use certificates from host inside ddev environment to connect a remote system

Tags: ssl-certificate, ddev

I try to connect a remote elastic cluster that is available from the host (Windows 10 Enterprise) system.

I tested the host's connection via curl https://url.to.target:443. Got that 'For sure, its search'-Response.

When i try the same from inside the webserver-container (Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)) it failes by:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it.
```

Is there a simple way use the hosts certificates store?

Answer (score 2):

- Copy yourcert.crt to .ddev/web-build folder.
- Create a custom .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile, for example:

```
    ARG BASE_IMAGE
    FROM $BASE_IMAGE
    COPY ./yourcert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
    RUN update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

- When referencing the cert in your code use:
  $myCert='/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/yourcert.crt';

Answer (score -1):

**!!! This is just a quick and dirty insecure workaround !!!

!!! Only use for testing if there is no other issue !!!

!!! Make sure you disable it as soon as your Certs are fixed !!!**

Have you tried it by adding the insecure option to the .curlc file in your Home dir?

```
echo insecure >> $HOME/.curlrc
```

**Shouldn't be used in production!**

Comment: downvoted as it only "fixes" curl and it makes it insecure for anything you use it on outside of your own project. A lot of tools use curl to download and run scripts to install themselves.

IMHO this is not good advice, even though it does make the error go away.

Comment: Your right @Nick - this was just a quick fix for our own internal gov cert hell. Proper way is what Jo Wu said above. Maybe better delete it?

Comment: Maybe, or edit with big warnings that it makes the error go away at the expense of removing a lot of the protections SSL provides :) It's a useful thing to know if you need it in an emergency, but it should be avoided as a permanent fix. And all developers know there is nothing in life more permanent than a temporary fix ;)

Comment: Done :-) Hope it is clear now.